# Abstract view of TFS code analysis rules?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've seen questions about Sonar with C# but I wonder if there's any tool to have a visualization of the code analysis rules in TFS ?

Basically, your code analysis rules can be a superset of your check-in rules, right ?

I'd like to have a Sonar-like view based on the code analysis rules on my projects, is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Code Analysis is a feature of Visual Studio, not of TFS.

One of the TFS check-in rules is to not permit check-in when there are code analysis warnings.